# Testing BigInsights + Cloud Storage (How to use nodejs over this two components)

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage, biginsights

Hi I have been trying to test this two components on bluemix since last 2 days, I need to now if both of then has some robust library on NodeJs, because I have been trying the ones I found at npm and event the one featured at Bluemix Cloud Storage as Nodejs SDK and I have unsuccessfull on even connect to Cloud Storage and Hive, I feel completly lost. I hope some one here could at least give e a lead ....

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Have you walked through the sample apps in the Bluemix docs and on GitHub? This link gives you hints for how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that the bluemix platform had an issue when creating the cloud storage within the Biginsights cluster manager, so I created the Object Storage first and then link it to the Biginsights service and now the NodeJs SDK from bluemix works just fine, thanks anyway.